# How To Retrieve all the List URL In SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, csom, sharepoint-server

I want to get all the list URL from SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell CSOM.

Some one could suggest on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my demo code for your reference:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$loginname="Contoso\administrator"
$pwd="password"
$siteUrl="http://sp13/sites/michael"
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($loginname, $pwd)
$lists=$Ctx.Web.Lists
$Ctx.load($lists)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($list in $lists){
$Ctx.Load($list.RootFolder)  
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$listurl="http://sp13"+$list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
write-host $listurl 
}
```

Comment: Thank you... it is working... may i know how to add the domain name like ("http://sp13") in the list URL

Comment: Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

```
param
(
[string] $URL,
[boolean] $WriteToFile = $true
)
 
#Get all lists in farm
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Counter variables
$webcount = 0
$listcount = 0
 
if($WriteToFile -eq $true)
{
    $outputPath = Read-Host "Outputpath (e.g. C:directoryfilename.txt)"
}
if(!$URL)
{
    #Grab all webs
    $webs = (Get-SPSite -limit all | Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}
else
{
    $webs = Get-SPWeb $URL
}
if($webs.count -ge 1 -OR $webs.count -eq $null)
{
    foreach($web in $webs)
    {
        #Grab all lists in the current web
        $lists = $web.Lists
        Write-Host "Website"$web.url -ForegroundColor Green
        if($WriteToFile -eq $true){Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value "Website $($web.url)"}
        
        foreach($list in $lists)
        {
            $listcount +=1
            Write-Host " – "$list.Title
            if($WriteToFile -eq $true){Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value " – $($list.Title)"}
        }
        $webcount +=1
        $web.Dispose()
    }
    #Show total counter for checked webs & lists
    Write-Host "Amount of webs checked:" $webcount
    Write-Host "Amount of lists:" $listcount
}
else
{
    Write-Host "No webs retrieved, please check your permissions" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

**Source**: [Get SharePoint lists by using PowerShell](https://sharepointrelated.com/2011/11/28/get-sharepoint-lists-by-using-powershell/)

With some little modifications in above code you can get all the required list details.

**Additional resources**:

1. [Get all lists in a Sharepoint Site using Powershell](https://morgantechspace.com/2016/03/get-all-lists-in-sharepoint-site-using-powershell.html)
2. [Extract all list names from sharepoint site to csv](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86842/extract-all-list-names-from-sharepoint-site-to-csv)
3. [Get All Lists and Libraries using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/sharepoint-online-get-all-lists-using-powershell.html)